# How to configure Quarkus to point to a non default name Neo4J DB?

Tags: neo4j, quarkus

Default configuration point to bolt://localhost:7687 and thus Neo4J DB but using entreprise edition you can create your own. Let's call it MyInstance

How to configure the uri to point to MyInstance using the plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver connects to a Neo4j server. You can then specify the database to use at the session level, for eg :

```
// imports
import org.neo4j.driver.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.SessionConfig;

// ... other code
try (Session session = driver.session(SessionConfig.forDatabase("movies"))) {
   session.writeTransaction((tx) -> {
      tx.run("CREATE (n:Movie {name: $name})", Map.of("name", "The Matrix"));
      return null;
   });
}
```